# Mongoose js create collection on start

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, meanjs

I have a MEAN js app. I need the collections to get created when it is started. Right now, it only gets created when I insert a document in it.

Can something be specified during schema creation?

Comment: Do you have indexes on your collections? It's not a direct solution to your problem, but if Mongoose has to create indexes then it must also create the collections.

Comment: Its a default MEAN js app, so I'm not sure :(

Comment: I just tried `mySchema.set('autoIndex',true);` didnt create on launch

Comment: Try indexing a specific field that you will query on. For example: `name: {type: String, index: true}`.

Comment: Worked! Thank you lord @weiyin! Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to make sure you have at least one field indexed. Mongoose will create the collection when it creates the indexes.

For example, to index the `name` field, specify this in your schema: `name: {type: String, index: true}`.